# Converting Tab separated file to csv file

Tags: scala, csv

I am new to scala and spark, I am trying to convert a Tab saparated file into CSV file to further convert it into RDD.
Actually I tried to convert Tab separated file to RDD using `sc.textFile` . It is getting implemented but the results afterwards like `.first()` , `.take(n)` are not very systematic and unable to read properly even after using `foreach(println)`.
I tried converting the file to csv using Excel but the data size being very large, It is not getting loaded at the first place.
Is there any simple ay **to convert Tab separated file to CSV** so as to get systematic results for the above mentioned problem.

Comment: http://carminedimascio.com/2015/02/apache-spark-convert-csv-to-rdd/ maybe you could provide what you have tried so far and a sample of your csv?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33898041

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mini tutorial:

Let's say your TSV data is:

`row11 \t row12 \t row13... \t row1n
row21 \t row22 \t row23... \t row2n`

Read this file as an RDD of strings:

`val readFile = sc.textFile("FILEPAHT HERE")`

Parse it's contents by using the tab delimiter:

`val parseRows = readFile.map(row => row.split("\t"))`

Convert the row arrays into a string delimited by ","

`val outputCsvRdd = parseRows.map(row => row.mkString(","))`

Write out the file which would be a csv:

`outputCsvRdd.saveAsTextFile('OUTPUTPATH')`